# How can I copy a directory except for all of the hidden files in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a directory hierarchy with a bunch of files.  Some of the directories start with a `.`.
I want to copy the hierarchy somewhere else, leaving out all files and dirs that start with a `.`

How can one do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is [File::Copy::Recursive](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm)'s `rcopy_glob()`:

> rcopy_glob()
>
> This function lets you specify a
>   pattern suitable for perl's glob() as
>   the first argument. Subsequently each
>   path returned by perl's glob() gets
>   rcopy()ied.
>
> It returns and array whose items are
>   array refs that contain the return
>   value of each rcopy() call.
>
> It forces behavior as if
>   $File::Copy::Recursive::CPRFComp is
>   true.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to actually use rcopy_glob to do this, and didn't manage to find an example on the web. How would you actually use rcopy_glob to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to solve this problem without Perl, you should check out `rsync`. It's available on Unix-like systems, on Windows via cygwin, and perhaps as a stand-alone tool on Windows. It will do what you need and a whole lot more.

```
rsync -a -v --exclude='.*' foo/ bar/
```

If you aren't the owner of all of the files, use `-rOlt` instead of `-a`.

Answer (score 0):

Glob ignores dot files by default.

`perl -lwe'rename($_, "foo/$_") or warn "failure renaming $_: $!" for glob("*")'`

Comment: this isn't copy, it is a move, and it isn't recursive.

Comment: glob doesn't ignore hidden files, it just returns the files you ask for. It's the '*' pattern that doesn't match a leading . . A slight nit, but important to know who's ignoring what. :)

Comment: The function ignores directory entries. readdir and it's there, use a shell-style glob with bsd_glob and it's not, use a text or dos glob and it is.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does the job in a simple way but doesn't handle symlinks, for example.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Find;
use File::Spec::Functions qw/ abs2rel catfile file_name_is_absolute rel2abs /;

die "Usage: $0 src dst\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my($src,$dst) = @ARGV;

$dst = rel2abs $dst unless file_name_is_absolute $dst;
$dst = catfile $dst, basename $src if -d $dst;

sub copy_nodots {
  if (/^\.\z|^[^.]/) {
    my $image = catfile $dst, abs2rel($File::Find::name, $src);

    if (-d $_) {
      mkdir $image
        or die "$0: mkdir $image: $!";
    }
    else {
      copy $_ => $image
        or die "$0: copy $File::Find::name => $image: $!\n";
    }
  }
}

find \&copy_nodots => $src;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -r .??*
```

almost perfect, because it misses files beginning with . and followed by a single sign. like - .d or .e

```
echo .[!.] .??*
```

this is even better

or:

```
shopt -s dotglob ; cp -a * destination; shopt -u dotglob
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [File::Copy::Recursive](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive)'s rcopy_glob().

The following is what is showed in the docs but is deceptive.

```
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(fcopy rcopy dircopy fmove rmove dirmove);
```

it does not import rcopy_glob() and the only way I found to use it was to be explict as follows:

```
use File::Copy::Recursive;

File::Copy::Recursive::rcopy_glob("glob/like/path","dest/path");
```